# Laravel get conversation where users in array

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

I am making a messaging app, and i need to check if a conversation already exists that has a certain list of users (no more, no less). I have this model:

```
class Conversation{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
    public function messages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }

}
```

I have these tables:

conversations:

- id
- user_id <- the owner of the conversation

users:

- id
- email
- password

conversation_user:

- id
- conversation_id
- user_id

I want to make a post request like this:

```
{
   "users": [1,4,6], <- user ids
   "message": "Some message"
}
```

If a conversation already exists with all and only users 1,4,6, the message should be added to that conversation to avoid having duplicate conversations in the database. Otherwise i will make a new conversation with the specified users.
This is the best i have been able to do so far:

```
$existing_conversation = $user->conversations()->whereHas('users', 
    function($query) use ($data){
        $query->whereIn('user_id', $data['users']);
    }
)->has('users', '=', count($data['users']));
```

But it just returns the conversations that has exactly the amount of users that was in the users array. It ignores the inner query..

Does anyone have an idea for this? :)

Comment: Hey @Donkarnash . That didn't make any difference :(

Comment: It is unclear from the code provided, it seems that Conversation and User models share Many-to-Many relation through a pivot table. In that case, how are you able to check for user_id on conversations? Please provide the table and Model details of user and conversation for understanding your current code structure

Comment: Hey @Donkarnash .
You are rigth. I have edited the question to include the table structure. conversation_user is a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
$existing_conversation = $user->conversations()->wherePivotIn('user_id', $data['users'])->has('users', count($data['users'])->get();
```

Haven't tested, should work I think.

**UPDATE**

Not a very elegant solution, however it works. You can add some helper methods in your controller like

```
//Get user's conversations with no of users equal to count($data['users']);
protected function get_conversations_with_equal_users(User $user, array $user_ids)
{
    return $user->conversations()
                ->wherePivotIn('user_id', $user_ids)
                ->has('users', '=', count($user_ids))
                ->get();
}

//Get the id of a user conversation with exactly same users as $data['users'] if it exists otherwise it will return 0;
protected function get_existing_conversation_id(User $user, array $user_ids)
{
    $existing_conversation_id = 0;
    $user_conversations_with_equal_users = $this->get_conversations_with_equal_users($user, $user_ids);

    foreach($user_conversations_with_equal_users as $conv)
    {
        $ids = [];
        foreach($conv->users as $user)
        {
            $ids[] = $user->id;
        }
        if($this->array_equal($user_ids, $ids))
        {
            $existing_conversation_id = $conv->id;
        }

    }
    return $existing_conversation_id;
}

//Function to compare two arrays for equality.
protected function array_equal($a, $b) {
    return (
        is_array($a) && is_array($b) &&
        count($a) == count($b) &&
        array_diff($a, $b) === array_diff($b, $a)
    );
}
```

The you can use the following in your controller to get the existing conversation for user (if it exists)

```
$existing_conversation_id = $this->get_existing_conversation_id($user, $data['users']);
    if($existing_conversation_id)
    {
        $existing_conversation = Conversation::with('users')
            ->whereId($existing_conversation_id)
            ->get();
    }
```

Comment: It just returns the conversations that has the right number of users.

Comment: @Bisgaard  I have edited my answer with a suggestion for an alternate approach to what you are trying to accomplish - have a look . Can it work for you?

Comment: the reason i want to find the conversations that has the specified users, is to avoid having dublicate conversations in the database. I already have the message belongs to conversation functionality.. I just left it out of the question for simplicity :)

Comment: I am not able to understand. When a user initiates a Conversation - persist it to the database and attach the id of Conversation (in the view - using ajax), then subsequently other users exchange messages in the conversation. Each time a message is added to the conversation the post request to the api can contain [user_ids, conversation_id, message] - in the api you can store the message with conversation_id, update the conversation_user pivot with the user_ids. - Am I missing something?

Comment: The API endpoint i am working on is the one to create a new conversation. I just want to prevent, that two conversations can be created with the exact same users.

Comment: Hmm.. So it means that when a new conversation is initiated in the view(front end) there can already be multiple users associated with the conversation even before it is persisted to the database right?

Comment: Consider this. There is a conversation record in the database that has 3 users associated (1,4,6). Then i try to create a new conversation from the frontend with the users 1,4 and 6. This should not be possible because it would cause a dublicate entry in the database. So i want to check wether a conversation already exists with those users, and if it doesn't i will create a new conversation. If it DOES exist, i will return the existing conversation.

Comment: Okay I understand. Will have to create your tables and seed some sample data to play around. Will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks that's awesome :)

Comment: I think the problem is, that "whereIn" matches any conversation where one of the users in the array are. Not all of them.

Comment: @Bisgaard I have added **UPDATE** to my answer. It is not a very elegant solution, but works  - tested with limited sample data.

Comment: Hey @Donkarnash - It's working as a charm :) But no it's not the most elegant solution.. But i will use that for now, and maybe i will find a better solution at some point :)